# What does "PostgreSQL layer has no primary key." when loading layer from database manager mean?

Tags: qgis, database-manager

I have a complex join that I have working in the database manager but when I try and load it nothing appears and I found this in the logs:
    `PostgreSQL layer has no primary key.`
What is actually wrong?

[image: screen shot of the SQL window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.  There was a duplicated row produced by the join so the gids were not actually unique.  I had checked that before but missed the duplicate entry.

To answer the question: `PostgreSQL layer has no primary key` means that the column you selected as having "unique integer values" in fact does not.

The other thing I discovered during this exercise is that one must have the log window open when doing complex stuff with the database manager.  Otherwise things appear to fail silently.

Comment: I will, but you have to wait two days ;)